# Are RSA keys generated in .NET affected by ROCA vulnerability?

Tags: c#, .net, security, rsa

A new [vulnerability called ROCA](https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3019326/roca-rsa-encryption-key-flaw-puts-millions-of-devices-at-risk) in [FAST PRIME algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52292/what-is-fast-prime/52832) in some RSA generators has been discovered.

Does it affect keys generated in .NET by [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class in past?

Comment: I think that the answer is yes. and this is why I vote to close your question :) (it is a debate opener rather than a technical programming 'how-to' question..)

Comment: I don't think the question is opinion-based, .NET is either affected or not. But it belongs to [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).